# Is this a good way to instantiate an object in a class with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I always find the code just like Code A in CameraX project. It creates instances using a object inside `companion object` within a class.

If I write the same code, I will use Code B.

Is it a good way to instantiate an object in a class with Kotlin? Is Code A better than Code B ?

BTW, I don't imagine that "Every Fragments class must have an empty constructor". Would you please consider a normal class instead of Fragments class?

**Code A**

```
class UIFragmentPhoto internal constructor() : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = ImageView(context)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val args = arguments ?: return
        val resource = args.getString(FILE_NAME_KEY)?.let { File(it) } ?: R.drawable.ic_photo
        Glide.with(view).load(resource).into(view as ImageView)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val FILE_NAME_KEY = "file_name"

        fun create(image: File) = UIFragmentPhoto().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(FILE_NAME_KEY, image.absolutePath)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Invoke A**

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = UIFragmentPhoto.create(mediaList[position])
```

**Code B (Modified)**

```
class UIFragmentPhoto internal constructor() : Fragment() {
    val FILE_NAME_KEY = "file_name"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = ImageView(context)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val args = arguments ?: return
        val resource = args.getString(FILE_NAME_KEY)?.let { File(it) } ?: R.drawable.ic_photo
        Glide.with(view).load(resource).into(view as ImageView)
    }


    constructor(image: File):this(){
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString(FILE_NAME_KEY, image.absolutePath)
        }
    }

}
```

**Invoke B (Modified)**

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = UIFragmentPhoto(mediaList[position])
```

Answer (score 4):

### In case of `Fragment`s:

According to the source code of the `Fragment` class on [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#491) where the default constructor is defined, we see that:

> **Every** fragment must have an
>   empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its
>   activity's state.  **It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not
>   have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors
>   will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated;** instead,
>   arguments can be supplied by the caller with [setArguments](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle))
>   and later retrieved by the Fragment with [getArguments](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()).
>
> Applications should generally not implement a constructor. Prefer
>   [onAttach(Context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)) instead. It is the first place application code can run where
>   the fragment is ready to be used - the point where the fragment is actually associated with
>   its context. Some applications may also want to implement [onInflate](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onInflate(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20android.os.Bundle)) to retrieve
>   attributes from a layout resource, although note this happens when the fragment is attached.

Referring to the above reason, adding **non-default constructors** in a `Fragment` is **PROHIBITED** !!!

After that, using `setArguments` and `getArguments` methods is the alternative way to avoid adding extra constructors. **Code B** written in question, uses these two approaches simultaneously. You should use one of them *i.e.* like **Code A**. (Because when you pass the parameter to the constructor, it is possible to access it in class. So there is no need for the `[set/get]Arguments` pattern)

However, if we want to rewrite the **Code B** without using arguments (*Disclaimer: I emphasize that this approach is not true*), we can do it like the following:

```
class UIFragmentPhoto internal constructor(private val image: File?) : Fragment() {

    constructor() : this(null)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = ImageView(context)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val resource = image ?: R.drawable.ic_photo
        Glide.with(view).load(resource).into(view as ImageView)
    }

}
```

### In general:

We all know that an object is created by calling the constructor method of the class in Java/Kotlin. For example:

```
val obj = MyClass()
```

When you want to create an object, there is no need for wrapping the constructor call in another function unless the nature of the object must be changed according to the nature of the program. Because it leads to imposing the burden of one extra function call to create an object without any advantages.

In the case of the changing objects according to the nature of the program, we must get the help of creational design patterns to provide more general and flexible approach (*like:* Factory Method, Abstract Factory, *etc.* Patterns).

## Conclusion:

1. When you are dealing with the creation of an object from **`Fragment`** classes, the **Code A** style should be used. (Because of the reason described in [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#491))
2. When you are dealing with the creation of an object from **non-`Fragment`** classes, the **Code B** style is better to be used. (Because of avoiding extra function call which has no advantage)

Comment: Thanks!  but I want to know whether  Code A is better than Code B  for  instantiate an object of  a normal class .  I don't imagine that `Every fragment class must have an empty constructor`. :(

Comment: So would you please treat `Fragment` as a normal class in Code A and Code B?, then tell me whether Code A is better than Code B. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is inefficient. Your Code B requires you to instantiate a throw-away copy of your fragment, just so you can call a factory method to create the actual fragment that you want.

Comment: It's not a throwaway copy - it's creating an instance, then manually initializing it, before returning that same instance.

Comment: @dominicoder - your code B includes the code `UIFragmentPhoto()` twice (once in `Invoke B`, once in `create()` - meaning two instances are created

Comment: Ah - you're correct, I missed that. I hope that was a typo on the OP's part.

Comment: Thanks! To  ianhanniballake: I modified Code B, now it create the object only one time!

Answer (score 0):

> Is a good way to instance a object in a class with Kotlin?

Not really. Also, this has nothing to do with Kotlin, it's a language-agnostic [*pattern*](https://www.google.com/search?q=static%20factory%20method).

If you initialize the Fragment your way (B) then you have three problems:

1) It would be easy to forget to call "create" on your instance:

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = UIFragmentPhoto() // Oops - bug
```

2) If you make `create` an instance method you could call it repeatedly on an existing fragment:

```
fun someFunction() {
    UIFragmentPhoto fragment = getExistingFragment()
    fragment.create() // Oops - just overwrote the fragment state
}
```

3) Having a method to "create" an instance that has already been created is just confusing and a non-standard way to initialize a fragment. The point of that static / companion way of doing it is that you have a function *who's job it is* to create and initialize the object.

A factory method also gives you the flexibility to do error handling / verification before returning the object and the opportunity to create a wholly different object type that extends / implements the return type if you so choose:

```
companion object {
    fun create(arg: Int): UIFragmentPhoto {
        if (arg == 0) throw IllegalStateException("Wasn't expecting 0!")
        if (arg == 1) return FragmentThatExtendsUIFragmentPhoto()
        if (arg == 2) return UIFragmentPhoto()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I can also use different `init {}` in Code B just like factory method.

Comment: And more, I modified the Code B,  and invoke it using `UIFragmentPhoto(mediaList[position])`, so  `It would be easy to forget to call "create" on your instance` will not occur again.

Comment: You cannot have a fragment with a constructor that takes arguments. When your fragment is killed and restored by the OS it will use the zero-args constructor to initialize the fragment and any initialization you would do in your constructor will not be called.

Comment: Thanks! I modified Code B, I use secondary constructor, so I can implement  'factory method ' for different case.

Comment: And more,  the error '1) It would be easy to forget to call "create" on your instance: ' would be also occur in Code A, it mean that `override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = UIFragmentPhoto() // Oops - bug`  can be complied corrcetly but failed when run if I use Code A

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, `object` property denotes a collection `Singleton` variables and methods by default.

```
object Singleton { // or whatever you name it
   //singleton members
}
```

It is lazy and thread-safe, it initializes upon first call, much as Java's static initializers.

You can declare an object at top level or inside a class or another object.

So, your object declaration inside a class can be marked with the companion keyword:

```
class UIFragmentPhoto {
    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): UIFragmentPhoto = UIFragmentPhoto()
    }
}
```

Members of the `companion object` can be called by using simply the class name as the qualifier:

```
val instance = UIFragmentPhoto.create()
```

If you only use `object` without `companion`, you have to do like this:

```
val instance = UIFragmentPhoto.Factory.create()
```

In my understanding, **`companion`** means this object is companion with the outer class.
So, yes you can obviously use the `instance` created in you Code A into Code B.
For any confusion let me know. I will try to help you further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fragments ***must*** have a public no-arguments constructor, and ***should*** not have other constructors besides that one; instead, any arguments that the fragment needs should be put in its `arguments` Bundle. This is because when Android needs to dynamically construct fragments, it does so by calling the empty constructor.

As such, even if you wanted to use your code B (and it is not generally recommended), your default constructor should be public, in which case your secondary constructor simply serves the same role as the `create` method in code A.

Comment: Thanks! but I want to know whether Code A is better than Code B for instantiate an object of a normal class . I don't imagine that "Every fragment class must have an empty constructor". Would you please consider a normal class instead of Fragments class.